# getting parts of html file in php

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

i need to get two things out of an html file:

1. text between `<title>` and `</title>`
2. text between `<body>` and `</body>`

does anybody know how to do this? this is what i have so far:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
$title = preg_replace("/.*<title[^>]*>|<\/title>.*/si", "", $file);
$body = preg_replace("/.*<body[^>]*>|<\/body>.*/si", "", $file);
```

i need to echo the title in a textbox and the body in a textarea.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Read [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use regex to parse HTML.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Instead, use [`DOMDocument::LoadHTML`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).